# htacess rule for forwarding from www to http

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:\/\/example.com\/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I create the above rule to avoid site duplicacy
Also
http://www.example.com is pointing to http://example.com

but the issue i am facing is i am not able to move any urls like
http://www.example.com/xyz/abc is not pointing to http://example.com.

Please help

Comment: What does happen instead? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @OlafDietsche no error msg, its not forwarding

Comment: Maybe there's another rule before this one handling the request.